sublime text 4 api - changing a view which is not current
I am trying to make changes to all views in the current window.
I am able to access and process each view, but changes using view.insert() and view.update() only occur in the current view.
Here is a bit of test code:
    # Get ref to the active window
    window = self.view.window()
    update_count = 0

    if window:
        # Iterate through all open views in the window
        for view_to_update in window.views():
            view_to_update.insert(edit, 0, 'new_content\n')

